# ADO.NET: How to represent a selection of exactly one row from a table?

Tags: c#, xml, database-design, ado.net

I have an ADO.NET DataSet that is persisted as XML. I need to add to it a list of cities and allow the user to select which city they're in. The selection has to be stored in the XML file along with the rest of the data.

This seems like a perfect use for `DataSet.ExtendedProperties`. However, it turns out that, in order for the extended properties to get written to the XML, I need to use `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema` and `XmlReadMode.ReadSchema`, which adds the entire schema of the DataSet to the XML file just so it can add a single attribute, `msprop:CityID`.

My DataSet is strongly typed and its schema is hard-coded by the designer, so I really don't need to store the schema in the XML, which can lead to run-time errors.

So my question is, what's the best way to add the selected city to the DataSet itself. For example, using another table called `SelectedCity`, or using a Boolean column in the `City` table called `IsSelected`.

The `SelectedCity` table will always need to contain exactly one row, and the `IsSelected` column will need to contain `true` in exactly one row and `false` in all the others, and I don't know how to enforce such constraints in ADO.NET.

This seems like a fairly common scenario. What's the recommended way to code it?

Answer (score 0):

If the relation is 1 to 1 put the field in the parent, but if a user can have various 1 to N put in another table. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Which relation are you referring to?

Comment: The list of cities is the same for all Users? Or depend which user is. If It is only one list for all Users use isselected field inside the list.

Comment: This is not a client-server application. Each user has their own installation, and the list of cities is read from one of the installed files, but I also want to put it in the dataset so it can be displayed in a data-bound control.

Comment: Add this in isselected field then, it's the best way.